# NGINXaaS Configuration

Tags: azure, nginx-config

Im trying to create a gateway in azure's NGINX with a/b testing feature.
I manged to find the configuration from the web

```
http {
    # Set up a key‑value store to specify the percentage to send to each 
    # upstream group based on the 'Host' header.

    keyval_zone zone=split:64k state=/etc/nginx/state_files/split.json;
    keyval $host $split_level zone=split;

    upstream appversion1 {
        zone appversion1 64k;
        server 192.168.50.100;
        server 192.168.50.101;
    }

    upstream appversion2 {
        zone appversion2 64k;
        server 192.168.50.102;
        server 192.168.50.103;
    }

    split_clients $client_ip $split0 {
        *   appversion1;
    }
    split_clients $client_ip $split5 {
        5%  appversion2;
        *   appversion1;
    }
    split_clients $client_ip $split10 {
        10% appversion2;
        *   appversion1;
    }
    split_clients $client_ip $split25 {
        25% appversion2;
        *   appversion1;
    }
    split_clients $client_ip $split50 {
        50% appversion2;
        *   appversion1;
    }
    split_clients $client_ip $split100 {
        *   appversion2;
    }

    map $split_level $upstream {
        0        $split0;
        5        $split5;
        10       $split10;
        25       $split25;
        50       $split50;
        100      $split100;
        default  $split0;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # In each 'split_clients' block above, '$client_ip' controls which 
        # application receives each request. For a production application, we set it
        # to '$remote_addr' (the client IP address). But when testing from just one 
        # client, '$remote_addr' is always the same; to get some randomness, we set 
        # it to '$request_id' instead.

        #set $client_ip $remote_addr; # Production
        set $client_ip $request_id; # Testing only

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://$upstream;
        }
    }
}
```

But when trying to upload it to azure split_clients doesn't work and get this error - unknown directive "*" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:21.

I tried to change the * to 100% / change the location and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket with F5 (The company maintaining the service) and they have a bug in parsing split_clients in the configuration file. Should be fixed in the near future...